# AJAX File Upload return value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I am using this AJAX File Uploader

http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

I using this code:

```
function ajaxFileUpload() {
    $('input[type=file]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url: 'upload.php',
                secureuri: false,
                fileElementId: this.id,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    $('body').html(data);
                },
            })
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I want the body's html turn into whatever I echo out from upload.php like what we usually do using $.ajax unfortunately when I echo out something from upload.php even if it is just a simple string, $('body')'s html is turned blank. Nothing is returned. Can anyone help ?

Comment: A blank response usually indicates a 500 Internal Server Error. Check your error log and use something like Firebug to check the response code and response data of your ajax calls.

Comment: one thing I observed was when i do alert(data) it returns an HTML object. There are no errors logged in firebug. I tried putting in the error function of this plugin and the error did not fire as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('body').html(data.msg);`

Comment: tried that already. didn't work :( I had a $msg = 'msg'; echo $msg in my upload.php and yet nothing worked.

Comment: The response must be json:
`echo json_encode(array('msg' => $msg));`

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the website you linked to, it is returning an object, not a string which is what you are trying to insert into the `body`.

`success` is expecting `data` to be an object, if you are echoing strings from `upload.php` then it won't be an object. Try building a JSON object and echoing that:

```
$out = new stdClass;
$out->error = '';
$out->msg = 'this is the message returned';

echo json_encode($out);
exit();
```

Try `data.msg` in the `success` javascript part.

Comment: tried that already. when I tried to alert(data.msg); it shows undefined. If i tried body.html(data.msg) it does not do anything.

Comment: If the example code on the website isn't working then there is something wrong with the either the Javascript or PHP. Try getting that to work before modifying the return code.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and came across this thread. Well, here the question is still unanswered. I found out the solution - in the ajax call, we need to pass the dataType of the response as well. It could be "html", "JSON" etc. So if you are facing a similar kind of issue try passing dataType. In my case I was getting File Type Error so that gave a clue.